# What is best way to generate a list of button/links dynamically

Tags: asp.net, button, dynamic

I am building an in house application for a restaurant. I am not sure what is the best approach to create a list of button/link dynamically.

I have list of combo meal box let say box1,  box2,  box3 (the count of combo box will change) which will be displayed on the screen. On selecting a given box a popup will be displayed having a list of items say item1...item5. User can choose form the items and proceed.

I am want to implement a list of button or links which will act like the list of combo box and a pop up panel for each button to display the items and proceed.

Please guide me what is best approach to create a dynamic list of buttons/links. Is button the right control or something else can be used to invoke the panel.

I am using asp.net (vs 2010) to build the app.

Comment: It would help if you mentioned and tagged the GUI technology/framework and platform you are planning to use.

Comment: Which technology you are looking for? Explain your need little bit more clear please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this little information, only a very generic recommendation can be made.

First, the difference between a link and a button:

- **link** is meant to take you to places, it never uses `POST` method and **SHOULD** not change any state in the server and should therefore be regarded as *robot safe* (meaning search engine spiders **WILL** follow links)
- **button**, especially in HTML5, is a generic UI element that can be made to do many different things (e.g with help from JavaScript), but generally is **NOT** regarded as *robot safe* meaning that search engine spiders probably won't click buttons (definitley not, if they are bound to `POST` forms though Google is now rendering JavaScript and might follow `GET` forms).

From the above - if your popped-up panel is just a sub-menu kind of thing with links in it, probably a `<a href="#">` link is good.

But if the popped-up panel is a `form` that triggers some changes in the server (e.g. adds something to cart etc) then `<button>` is better to convey the real purpose of the panel.

As to generating the layout, current best practice is to use `<ul>`, iterate over all your meal boxes and generate a `<li>` element for each. Then use CSS to set with and height of each box and JavaScript to pop up the panel.

For example something like this:

```
<ul class="mealboxes">
  <li class="mealbox"><button id="box1" class="mealbox">Meal Box 1</button></li>
  <li class="mealbox"><button id="box2" class="mealbox">Meal Box 2</button></li>
  <li class="mealbox"><button id="box3" class="mealbox">Meal Box 3</button></li>
</ul>
```

Using the classes attach CSS and click event handler and using the button ID you know which meal box button was clicked, so you can pop up the correct panel.

PS: To hide the list item bullets, use CSS similar to this:

```
ul.mealboxes {
 list-style: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Laas. Is there a way we can implement using a server side control.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know much about ASP.NET, but I'd assume you'd have to iterate over your mealboxes and for each element create a `runat="server"` button.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the id of the div you want to populate with buttons and/or links is: cat
Then use jQuery:

```
$('#cat').html('<input type="button" name="" value="Button1"/>');
```

To add more text:

```
 $('#cat').append('<a href="http://www.google.com">Click Here</a>');
```